Error while trying to read value from pointer with pymem
This is my first project where i want to read value from offset in one game but it gives me error: An error occurred:

Could not read memory at: 1436923512, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299.

import pymem
import pymem.process

PROCESS_NAME = "1v1_LOL.exe"
BASE_POINTER = 0x0449BF58
OFFSETS = [0x38, 0x20, 0x10, 0x68, 0x100, 0x0, 0xB8]

def get_pointer_value(pm, base_address, offsets):
    address = base_address
    for offset in offsets[:-1]:
        address = pm.read_int(address) + offset
    value = pm.read_int(address + offsets[-1])
    return value

try:
    pm = pymem.Pymem(PROCESS_NAME)
    module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "GameAssembly.dll").lpBaseOfDll
    base_address = module + BASE_POINTER
    value = get_pointer_value(pm, base_address, OFFSETS)
    print(f"Pointer value: {value}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Here is screenshot form cheatengine:cheatenginescrrenshot

I would start by finding out what error #299 is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499

@001 Page not found.

@Barmar Thanks. Missing a char at the end: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
